# ActiveRecord how to set associated attributes from a hash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have an ActiveRecord model instance where I want to modify attributes where some attributes exist on an association rather than directly on the model itself.  All of the attributes come in as a hash.

This code is part of my test suite so I'm not concerned about issues of mass attribute assignment in this case.

If I try to update using `instance.update_attributes(hash)` this fails.

As an alternative I tried looping over the hash and setting the attributes like this.

```
hash.each do |key, val|
  instance[key] = val
end
```

This method will set attributes that exist directly on the instance, but throws an exception on attributes that are tied to associated records `ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError Exception: can't write unknown attribute 'foo'`

Answer (score 1):

Give the [delegate](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Module.html#method-i-delegate) approach a go. Something along the lines of:

```
  class Foo
    attr_accessor :bar, :foo_attribute
    delegate :bar_attribute=, to: :bar

    def initialize
      @bar = Bar.new
    end
  end

  class Bar
    attr_accessor :bar_attribute
  end
```

Then, in the console:

```
  hsh = {foo_attribute: 'foo', bar_attribute: 'bar'}
  f = Foo.new
  hsh.each do |k,v|
    f.send("#{k}=",v)
  end
  f.inspect
   => "#<Foo:0x00000004f1f0f0 @bar=#<Bar:0x00000004f1f0c8 @bar_attribute=\"bar\">, @foo_attribute=\"foo\">" 
  f.bar.inspect
   => "#<Bar:0x00000004f1f0c8 @bar_attribute=\"bar\">"
```